# How can I save the state of my bot's activity with json?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I have these functions that change the bot's state

```
async def change_game(bot, game):
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=game))
    save_latest_activity(0, game)
```

And I would like to save this state (hence the save_latest_activity function). But i'm not sure how exactly to save it. Since there are 4 states it could be in, some with different amounts of parameters it seems difficult. Here is my current json for the streaming, gaming, listening and watching states:

```
    activity_json = {
        "playing": [
            {
                "game": data1
            }
        ],
        "streaming": [
            {
                "name": data1,
                "url": data2
            }
        ],
        "listening": [
            {
                "name": data1
            }
        ],
        "watching": [
            {
                "name": data1
            }
        ]
    }
```

I also have this enum to know the state that needs to be saved:

```
class ActivityType(enum.Enum):
    playing = 0
    streaming = 1
    listening = 2
    watching = 3
```

How can I save the specific state and data from these states and restore it when the bot is restarted? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finn!
You cal store all bot`s variables and parameters in dictionary and dump it to file like that

```
import json, pickle
with open('BOT_STATE_NAME.pkl', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(sample, fp)
```

Then, when your bot will be changing it`s state, you cal load all saved data back

```
data_file = open(path_to_file, "rb")
data_dict = pickle.load(data_file)
```

Comment: Hi! this is exactly what I was looking for! Can this save a class full of variables to file?

Comment: I am getting the error _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '{'.
when using the following:
```
    data_file = open("latest_activity.pkl", "rb")
    activity = pickle.load(data_file) # Error here

    activity_type = activity.get('last_activity') == 0
    data1 = activity.get('data1')
    data2 = activity.get('data2')

    if activity_type == 0:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=data1))
```

Comment: @user14196173, Found something that might help. When you are saving this dict to a file with open() func, use parameter 'wb' instead of 'w'. 
`open("BOT_STATE_NAME.pkl", "wb")`